# I need some help; can Lazy evaluation be used when comparing Data types?

Tags: haskell

`data Person = Person { name :: String, age :: Int} deriving(Show)`

Describe approximately how you can get Haskell to use (==) so that it evaluates True when two Person's have the same name, but different ages.

Is this possible to write with Lazy evaluation (e.g. that it compares the names without evaluating the ages of the two Persons)?

Comment: Yes, you can implement that manually, or `deriving (Ord)`. Only in case the two names are equal, it will then need to evaluate the `age` which then acts as a *tie-breaker*.

Comment: If it's not too much trouble - can you help me describe how this can be written as to use Lazy evaluation? 

I'm a bit afraid I have misunderstood something as a TA said Lazy evaluation was not applicable here, so I would appreciate a pointer (or help). ^^''

Comment: This is nothing to do with lazy evaluation. You would simply need the appropriate `Eq` instance. (However, in real programming as opposed to for an exercise, having the `(==)` do this would not be a good idea. You can simply write a separate function called something like `haveSameName`.)

Comment: you are just asked to describe - why not just "I'd have to write a instance of `Eq` for `Person` - when providing the definition for `==` I'd need to make sure that .... - Having said that it's not a good idea because such a instance would invalidate the law .... because of ..." (hint look at the laws [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Eq) and think about what laws hold and where you walk into trouble with an equality given here)

Comment: I find the problem statement you were given frustratingly ambiguous. I have a pretty good guess what is meant, but to illustrate what I find frustrating: What should `(==)` return when two Persons have the same name and same ages? If I implement `(==)` to always return `True`, is that acceptable? (It certainly meets the spec as stated.)

Answer (score 2):

The problem statement:

> Get Haskell to use (==) so that it evaluates True when two Person's have the same name but different ages.

Your question statement:

> Is it possible to write... [so] that it compares the names without evaluating the ages of the two Persons?

Do you see the difference? The problem statement says nothing about evaluation. You have inadvertently added an additional requirement, that wasn't demanded from you by the instructor. This is why your TA says this has nothing to do with lazy evaluation: the problem can be solved in today's Haskell, and could still be solved in tomorrow's Haskell even if Haskell became strict tomorrow.

Here's a small skeleton to get you started:

```
instance Eq Person where
    Person { name = nm, age = a } == Person { name = nm', age = a' }
        = {- ... write some code here ... -}
```